An equality for a $1$ periodic continuous function.
Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous such that $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$. Fix some $a \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ so an irrational number. Prove
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(ka)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx.$$
So the hint says to first prove this for trig polynomials, so say $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$ then I wanna say if I multiply the sum on the LHS by $f(a)$ may do the trick since that multiplication is permutation around complex unit circle then take the limit of that, but other than that im pretty lost and confused. Any hints or tips greatly appreciated. However the exp map is $2\pi$ periodic. Is the hint asking me to go from the $2\pi$ periodic case to the $1$ periodic case? This is the only exercise on this weeks homework set where I am very confused.
Also, I was unable to find a similar post so if there is one, please direct me to it! Also, does this help?
Also, if I follow the hint and use $f(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$, then the RHS is $0$. So its enough to show the LHS is zero?

Note that $e^{2\pi imx}$ is periodic with period $1$ and integrates to zero when $|m| \ge 1$; on the other hand the LHS sum is geometric and is easily seen to be bounded by a constant times the distance from $|ma|$ to the closest integer (which is a fixed non zero number as $a$ irrational) so when you divide by $n$ you go to zero; then use the fact that any continuous periodic function on $[0,1])$ is uniformly approximated by trigonometric polynomials (this sometimes is called Feijer Theorem) for which the result holds (as it obviously does for $f(x)=1$ which corresponds to $m=0$) to conclude

@Conrad what do you mean by geometric?

$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i mkx}$ is a geometric sum
